# Possible memory leaks after using malloc

Tags: c, ubuntu, memory-leaks

I worked on my school project. I used malloc quite badly without free. Since then my computer has been much slower and I am afraid that memory leaks could be the reason for it. I use Ubuntu 20.04.

I tried to restart it but it is still slow many days after it.
Can I somehow check if memory leaks are the problem and solve it?

Comment: The effects of memory leaks caused by not calling `free` are limited to the lifetime of the process. It's not relevant once the process has exit, and it's definately not the reason for the PC to be slow right after a restart.

Comment: An ill-behaved process is not able to consume memory beyond its lifetime. Restarting has definitely reset the state.

Comment: Memory leaks don't work like that, they are not persistent.  When the process terminates regardless of how much memory it has claimed, it is all returned to the operating system.  A system may slow when some process is consuming much of the CPU time or when cumulatively processes have consumed so much memory that disk-swapping occurs.  You need some sort of system monitor tool to see what is happening, but it that is off-topic here.

Comment: ... although you should understand that all semi-conductor chips contain smoke installed at manufacture - if you let the smoke out, the chips will stop working. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computer might slow down if your program is still running and it has some big memory leaks, but I don't believe that it would affect your computer when the program is shut down and it ends the execution.

When the program exits and finishes the execution, all the memory is freed by the kernel implicitly. That mempory will be used next time your computer needs to allocate new memory.